# How to detach drawer from soft close drawer slides?

Tags: bathroom

[image][image]I bought a Orchard Derwent bathroom unit with sliding drawers and need to take the drawers out to connect the waste pipe but these have got me baffled.
There doesn't appear to be any catches to move to be able to release the drawers.
The grey catch you see in the photograph doesn't seem to move.
Anyone dealt with this type before?

Comment: Are we looking at 2 different views of the same drawer or 2 different drawers? Is one of the pics upside down?

Comment: Pretty sure the "grey catch" you refer to slides toward the center of the drawer bottom. It sticks into a hole that is drilled in the wood drawer side.

Comment: I've not used these slides before, but I'd try removing the brass-color screws at the end of the slide in your second picture.

Comment: @Triplefault has it... they added a screw so things wouldn't fall apart... In the normal course of things, the grey lever would push into a hole in the drawer side to lock the unit down.

Comment: Yep, it was the brass coloured screws that kept the drawers on the glides. Once they were removed the drawers came out  straight away. -- The annoying thing is that there wasn't any kind of basic information in the product leaflet.

Answer (score 1):

The brass-colored screw visible at the end of the slide under the drawer in the second picture is holding the slide in place. Removing the brass screw will allow the drawer to be removed.